# xpath how access nodes by position

Tags: xpath, position, msxml6

I have such xml file

```
<ce:MarkInfo>
<ce:boxpos>
<ce:boxnumber>box-00112</ce:boxnumber>
<ce:amclist>
<ce:amc>12</ce:amc>
<ce:amc>22</ce:amc>
</ce:amclist>
</ce:boxpos>
<ce:boxpos>
<ce:boxnumber>box-00113</ce:boxnumber>
<ce:amclist>
<ce:amc>32</ce:amc>
<ce:amc>42</ce:amc>
<ce:amc>52</ce:amc>
<ce:amc>62</ce:amc>
</ce:amclist>
</ce:boxpos>
</ce:MarkInfo>
```

and xpath expression

```
xDoc.selectNodes("/ns:Documents/ns:Document/ns:WayBill_v3/wb:Content/wb:Position[1]/wb:InformF2/ce:MarkInfo//ce:amc").length = 6

/ns:Documents/ns:Document/ns:WayBill_v3/wb:Content/wb:Position[1]/wb:InformF2/ce:MarkInfo//ce:amc[1]
```

returns AMC value begins with 12

```
/ns:Documents/ns:Document/ns:WayBill_v3/wb:Content/wb:Position[1]/wb:InformF2/ce:MarkInfo//ce:amc[3]
```

returns AMC value begins with 52

```
/ns:Documents/ns:Document/ns:WayBill_v3/wb:Content/wb:Position[1]/wb:InformF2/ce:MarkInfo//ce:amc[5]
```

returns null

how can i access nodes by they absolute position, not by position in ce:amclist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"how can i access nodes by they absolute position, not by position in `ce:amclist`?"*

Wrap the entire XPath in parentheses, and add the position predicate outside :

```
(/ns:Documents/.....//ce:amc)[5]
```